# What are some problems with having $ in file names?

Tags: cross-platform, special-characters, compatibility, filenames

I'm trying to convince fellow developers to not include `$` in file names but couldn't come up any argument other than some Perl scripts may need to be updated.  Any suggestions?

Comment: nothing wrong with $ in filenames. unless you're eval()-ing code that contains such a filename somehow in a language where $ is used for variables. And if you're eval()ing code, you deserve any pain you suffer from such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance at Wikipedia's [Filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) page reveals that only zOS and Commodore DOS disallow the user of `$` appearing in certain file names. I can see why you would have trouble coming up with a reason not to use them.